# How can convert XML to PDF using iTextSharp?

Tags: asp.net, xml, itext

How can convert XML to PDF using iTextSharp?
the iTextSharp's current XML to PDF is clearly out of date and does not work. So I went about fixing the problem but i am not been able to covert it Can any one help me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <SR.No>14</SR.No>
    <test>loss test</test>
    <code>ISO-133</code>
    <unit>gm</unit>
    <sampleid>36</sampleid>
    <boreholeid>21</boreholeid>
    <pieceno>63</pieceno>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <SR.No>24</SR.No>
    <test>sand</test>
    <code>ISO-133</code>
    <unit>gm</unit>
    <sampleid>71</sampleid>
    <boreholeid>22</boreholeid>
    <pieceno>23</pieceno>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <SR.No>25</SR.No>
    <test>clay</test>
    <code>ISO-133</code>
    <unit>mg</unit>
    <sampleid>52</sampleid>
    <boreholeid>21</boreholeid>
    <pieceno>36</pieceno>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

Comment: It's a pretty nasty API (or at least it was 5 years ago). I used it years ago at university. Will try and dig out some code samples when I get home. If you Google hard enough, you should be able to find multiple examples that you can piece together. It's definitely out there.

Comment: @Goober thanks. But there aren't much elements and attributes where i can convert the XML in proper table format as we can do without using the Xml where we can just create a table structure and adding data to it in which ever format we want.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. Fundamentally you need a good understanding of XML to perform this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really trivial to do on your own. You didn't specify a language so the sample below uses VB.Net since (I think) it handles XML more easily. See the code comments for more details. This is targeting iTextSharp 5.4.4 but should work with pretty much any version.

```
''//Sample XML
Dim TextXML = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
              <catalog>
                  <cd>
                      <SR.No>14</SR.No>
                      <test>loss test</test>
                      <code>ISO-133</code>
                      <unit>gm</unit>
                      <sampleid>36</sampleid>
                      <boreholeid>21</boreholeid>
                      <pieceno>63</pieceno>
                  </cd>
                  <cd>
                      <SR.No>24</SR.No>
                      <test>sand</test>
                      <code>ISO-133</code>
                      <unit>gm</unit>
                      <sampleid>71</sampleid>
                      <boreholeid>22</boreholeid>
                      <pieceno>23</pieceno>
                  </cd>
                  <cd>
                      <SR.No>25</SR.No>
                      <test>clay</test>
                      <code>ISO-133</code>
                      <unit>mg</unit>
                      <sampleid>52</sampleid>
                      <boreholeid>21</boreholeid>
                      <pieceno>36</pieceno>
                  </cd>
              </catalog>

''//File to write to
Dim TestFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Test.pdf")

''//Standard PDF creation, nothing special here
Using fs As New FileStream(TestFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
    Using doc As New Document()
        Using writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs)
            doc.Open()

            ''//Create a table with one column for every child node of <cd>
            Dim T As New PdfPTable(TextXML.<catalog>.<cd>.First.Nodes.Count)

            ''//Loop through the first item to output column headers
            For Each N In TextXML.<catalog>.<cd>.First.Elements
                T.AddCell(N.Name.ToString())
            Next

            ''//Loop through each CD row (this is so we can call complete later on)
            For Each CD In TextXML.<catalog>.Elements
                ''//Loop through each child of the current CD
                For Each N In CD.Elements
                    T.AddCell(N.Value)
                Next

                ''//Just in case any rows have too few cells fill in any blanks
                T.CompleteRow()
            Next

            ''//Add the table to the document
            doc.Add(T)

            doc.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

**EDIT**

Here's a C# version. I've included a helper method to create a large XML document based on your template to show page overflow. The `PdfPTable` will automatically spam multiple pages. You can specify the number of rows that should be considered a "header" so that they repeat on subsequent pages. You'll probably want to also apply some formatting rules but you should be able to find those online (look for `PdfPTable.DefaultCell`)

```
private XDocument createXml() {
    //Create our sample XML document
    var xml = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"));

    //Add our root node
    var root = new XElement("catalog");
    //All child nodes
    var nodeNames = new[] { "SR.No", "test", "code", "unit", "sampleid", "boreholeid", "pieceno" };
    XElement cd;

    //Create a bunch of <cd> items
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        cd = new XElement("cd");
        foreach (var nn in nodeNames) {
            cd.Add(new XElement(nn) { Value = String.Format("{0}:{1}", nn, i.ToString()) });
        }
        root.Add(cd);
    }

    xml.Add(root);

    return xml;
}

private void doWork() {
    //Sample XML
    var xml = createXml();

    //File to write to
    var testFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "test.pdf");

    //Standard PDF creation, nothing special here
    using (var fs = new FileStream(testFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)) {
        using (var doc = new Document()) {
            using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs)) {
                doc.Open();

                //Count the columns
                var columnCount = xml.Root.Elements("cd").First().Nodes().Count();

                //Create a table with one column for every child node of <cd>
                var t = new PdfPTable(columnCount);

                //Flag that the first row should be repeated on each page break
                t.HeaderRows = 1;

                //Loop through the first item to output column headers
                foreach (var N in xml.Root.Elements("cd").First().Elements()) {
                    t.AddCell(N.Name.ToString());
                }

                //Loop through each CD row (this is so we can call complete later on)
                foreach (var CD in xml.Root.Elements()) {
                    //Loop through each child of the current CD. Limit the number of children to our initial count just in case there are extra nodes.
                    foreach (var N in CD.Elements().Take(columnCount)) {
                        t.AddCell(N.Value);
                    }
                    //Just in case any rows have too few cells fill in any blanks
                    t.CompleteRow();
                }

                //Add the table to the document
                doc.Add(t);

                doc.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks.I am using C# so i guess i need code in c#.Still i have one doubt that In my case static fields remains the same during pdf generation, only the data(values like test no, Unit, Is code will be dynamically attached to those static fields or labels so how should I keep on adding the new page as the data which I have in my XMl is very large and it will take multiple pdf pages to generate the report. So the defined table should remain the same only data should get properly attached to specific labels or field.

Comment: thanks for sharing the c# version. I have to do lot of modifications in that because my header is in vertical format and the columns should not exceed more than 6 per page after declaring the header. Thanks alot Chris.